# UIDatePicker UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer iPad Graphic Bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uidatepicker

I've just made a new UIView for my UIDatePicker. I was testing it with the default settings and all was ok (UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime) but as soon as I run `[[picker picker]];` hell breaks loose..

UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime Mode:
[image: UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime]

UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer Mode:
[image: UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer]

My debugger console also give 9 errors about not being able to find the mapped image for the following filenames:

- UITimerPickerFrameRight-180-Bar.png
- UITimerPickerFrameMiddle-180.png
- UITimerPickerFrameRight-180-Bar.png
- UITimerPickerBackground-180.png
- UITimerPickerFrameLeft-180-Bar.png
- UITimerPickerFrameMiddle-180.png
- UITimerPickerFrameRight-180-Bar.png
- UITimerPickerWheelBackground-180.png
- UITimerPickerWheelBackground-180.png

the exact error message is `Could not find mapped image [IMAGE NAME]`

the iPad i'm testing on is an iPad 2 running iOS5, this error can also be replicated on the iPad Simulator on both iOS 4 and 5.

Does anybody know of a walk around to this as the apps deadline is soon and I need this specific mode :/

I also haven't tried to replicate the issue on the iPhone as i know the clocks app doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are creating the `UIDatePicker` with a height of `216`.

The `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` mode has a problem with anything less than that height.

Comment: wow! thanks for the tip, works great now! that should be mentioned somewhere as i searched for quite a bit!

Comment: @L14M333 and if you'd like this to work with other heights, be sure to [request that ability](https://bugreport.apple.com).